# SNMPTRAPD receiving raw packets but the actual trap won't get logged or listen

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap, snmptrapd

I'm working on the SNMP trap. I'm using snmptrapd application to listen to SNMP traps, an issue with the snmptrapd unable to listen to the traps while it showing raw packets are coming when using **-d** option in snmptrapd command.

Here is my command `/usr/sbin/snmptrapd -afnd -Lf/tmp/trap.log -On -c /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf`
 Output for the following command is

```
Received 626 byte packet from UDP: [10.128.255.194]:45406->[10.7.254.1]:162
0000: 30 82 02 6E  02 01 03 30  0F 02 03 4F  D4 FA 02 02    0..n...0...O....
0016: 20 00 04 01  00 02 01 03  04 27 30 25  04 0B 80 00     ........'0%....
0032: 00 A1 03 52  54 00 01 E9  0A 02 01 04  02 04 01 04    ...RT...........
0048: 89 3A 04 09  4D 6F 74 6F  4E 6F 72 74  68 04 00 04    .:..MotoNorth...
0064: 00 30 82 02  2D 04 0B 80  00 00 A1 03  52 54 00 01    .0..-.......RT..
0080: E9 0A 04 06  6E 6F 41 75  74 68 A7 82  02 14 02 03    ....noAuth......
0096: 4F D4 F9 02  01 00 02 01  00 30 82 02  05 30 10 06    O........0...0..
0112: 08 2B 06 01  02 01 01 03  00 43 04 65  C5 9B 0D 30    .+.......C.e...0
0128: 19 06 0A 2B  06 01 06 03  01 01 04 01  00 06 0B 2B    ...+...........+
0144: 06 01 04 01  81 21 03 0A  68 01 30 13  06 0C 2B 06    .....!..h.0...+.
0160: 01 04 01 81  21 03 0A 69  03 00 02 03  08 08 2D 30    ....!..i......-0
0176: 22 06 0C 2B  06 01 04 01  81 21 03 0A  69 04 00 04    "..+.....!..i...
0192: 12 55 6E 6B  6E 6F 77 6E  45 76 65 6E  74 53 6F 75    .UnknownEventSou
0208: 72 63 65 30  12 06 0C 2B  06 01 04 01  81 21 03 0A    rce0...+.....!..
0224: 69 05 00 02  02 01 00 30  1C 06 0C 2B  06 01 04 01    i......0...+....
0240: 81 21 03 0A  69 06 00 04  0C 31 30 2E  31 2E 32 33    .!..i....10.1.23
0256: 33 2E 32 33  30 30 1C 06  0C 2B 06 01  04 01 81 21    3.2300...+.....!
0272: 03 0A 69 07  00 04 0C 31  30 2E 31 2E  32 33 33 2E    ..i....10.1.233.
0288: 32 33 30 30  1C 06 0C 2B  06 01 04 01  81 21 03 0A    2300...+.....!..
0304: 69 08 00 04  0C 31 30 2E  31 2E 32 33  33 2E 32 33    i....10.1.233.23
0320: 30 30 11 06  0C 2B 06 01  04 01 81 21  03 0A 69 09    00...+.....!..i.
0336: 00 02 01 05  30 1C 06 0C  2B 06 01 04  01 81 21 03    ....0...+.....!.
0352: 0A 69 0A 00  04 0C 31 30  2E 31 2E 32  33 33 2E 32    .i....10.1.233.2
0368: 33 30 30 1B  06 0C 2B 06  01 04 01 81  21 03 0A 69    300...+.....!..i
0384: 0B 00 04 0B  07 E3 02 1B  10 33 02 06  2B 05 1E 30    .........3..+..0
0400: 1B 06 0C 2B  06 01 04 01  81 21 03 0A  69 0C 00 04    ...+.....!..i...
0416: 0B 07 E3 02  1B 10 33 02  00 2B 05 1E  30 81 C3 06    ......3..+..0...
0432: 0C 2B 06 01  04 01 81 21  03 0A 69 0D  00 04 81 B2    .+.....!..i.....
0448: 45 76 65 6E  74 20 72 65  63 65 69 76  65 64 20 66    Event received f
0464: 72 6F 6D 20  61 6E 20 55  6E 6B 6E 6F  77 6E 20 49    rom an Unknown I
0480: 50 41 64 64  72 65 73 73  2E 20 48 70  53 77 69 74    PAddress. HpSwit
0496: 63 68 32 36  31 30 2D 34  38 2C 20 73  6E 6D 70 54    ch2610-48, snmpT
0512: 72 61 70 4F  49 44 20 3D  20 2E 31 2E  33 2E 36 2E    rapOID = .1.3.6.
0528: 31 2E 34 2E  31 2E 31 31  2E 32 2E 33  2E 37 2E 31    1.4.1.11.2.3.7.1
0544: 31 2E 37 37  2E 30 2E 32  2C 20 65 76  65 6E 74 44    1.77.0.2, eventD
0560: 65 73 63 72  69 70 74 69  6F 6E 2E 37  36 20 3A 20    escription.76 : 
0576: 49 20 30 32  2F 32 37 2F  31 39 20 31  31 3A 32 31    I 02/27/19 11:21
0592: 3A 30 32 20  70 6F 72 74  73 3A 20 70  6F 72 74 20    :02 ports: port 
0608: 31 39 20 69  73 20 6E 6F  77 20 6F 66  66 2D 6C 69    19 is now off-li
0624: 6E 65
Received 334 byte packet from UDP: [10.1.7.100]:161->[10.7.254.1]:162
0000: 30 82 01 4A  02 01 01 04  06 70 75 62  6C 69 63 A7    0..J.....public.
0016: 82 01 3B 02  01 00 02 01  00 02 01 00  30 82 01 2E    ..;.........0...
0032: 30 10 06 08  2B 06 01 02  01 01 03 00  43 04 01 1B    0...+.......C...
0048: 6B 0B 30 17  06 0A 2B 06  01 06 03 01  01 04 01 00    k.0...+.........
0064: 06 09 2B 06  01 04 01 CE  53 01 03 30  1D 06 0A 2B    ..+.....S..0...+
0080: 06 01 04 01  CE 53 01 03  01 04 0F 4E  56 52 2D 50    .....S.....NVR-P
0096: 48 31 2D 37  53 51 44 43  37 32 30 18  06 0A 2B 06    H1-7SQDC720...+.
0112: 01 04 01 CE  53 01 03 02  04 0A 31 30  2E 31 2E 37    ....S.....10.1.7
0128: 2E 31 30 30  30 14 06 0A  2B 06 01 04  01 CE 53 01    .1000...+.....S.
0144: 03 03 04 06  53 79 73 74  65 6D 30 16  06 0A 2B 06    ....System0...+.
0160: 01 04 01 CE  53 01 03 04  04 08 41 72  63 68 69 76    ....S.....Archiv
0176: 65 72 30 70  06 0A 2B 06  01 04 01 CE  53 01 03 05    er0p..+.....S...
0192: 04 62 53 4E  4D 50 20 61  67 65 6E 74  20 6F 66 20    .bSNMP agent of 
0208: 4C 61 74 69  74 75 64 65  20 61 70 70  6C 69 63 61    Latitude applica
0224: 74 69 6F 6E  20 41 72 63  68 69 76 65  72 20 61 74    tion Archiver at
0240: 20 4E 56 52  2D 50 48 31  2D 37 53 51  44 43 37 32     NVR-PH1-7SQDC72
0256: 20 69 73 20  61 6C 69 76  65 20 73 69  6E 63 65 20     is alive since 
0272: 32 2F 32 35  2F 32 30 31  39 20 31 3A  31 34 3A 35    2/25/2019 1:14:5
0288: 33 20 50 4D  30 28 06 0A  2B 06 01 04  01 CE 53 01    3 PM0(..+.....S.
0304: 03 06 04 1A  32 30 31 39  2D 32 2D 32  35 2C 31 33    ....2019-2-25,13
0320: 3A 31 34 3A  35 33 2E 33  2C 2B 35 3A  33 30          :14:53.3,+5:30

2019-02-27 16:51:03 UDP: [10.1.7.100]:161->[10.7.254.1]:162 [UDP: [10.1.7.100]:161->[10.7.254.1]:162]:
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (18574091) 2 days, 3:35:40.91   .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.10067.1.3    .1.3.6.1.4.1.10067.1.3.1 = STRING: "NVR-PH1-7SQDC72"    .1.3.6.1.4.1.10067.1.3.2 = STRING: "10.1.7.100" .1.3.6.1.4.1.10067.1.3.3 = STRING: "System" .1.3.6.1.4.1.10067.1.3.4 = STRING: "Archiver"   .1.3.6.1.4.1.10067.1.3.5 = STRING: "SNMP agent of Latitude application Archiver at NVR-PH1-7SQDC72 is alive since 2/25/2019 1:14:53 PM" .1.3.6.1.4.1.10067.1.3.6 = STRING: "2019-2-25,13:14:53.3,+5:30"
Received 67 byte packet from UDP: [10.12.90.1]:62459->[10.7.254.1]:162
0000: 30 41 02 01  00 04 06 70  75 62 6C 69  63 A4 34 06    0A.....public.4.
0016: 08 2B 06 01  04 01 81 B7  43 40 04 0A  0C 5A 01 02    .+......C@...Z..
0032: 01 06 02 01  03 43 01 00  30 19 30 17  06 0A 2B 06    .....C..0.0...+.
0048: 01 04 01 81  B7 43 01 02  04 09 4B 65  65 70 61 6C    .....C....Keepal
0064: 69 76 65                                              ive

2019-02-27 16:51:02 10.12.90.1(via UDP: [10.12.90.1]:62459->[10.7.254.1]:162) TRAP, SNMP v1, community public
    .1.3.6.1.4.1.23491 Enterprise Specific Trap (3) Uptime: 0:00:00.00
    .1.3.6.1.4.1.23491.1.2 = STRING: "Keepalive"
```

As you see **10.128.255.194**, this IP traps won't get logged, only showing the raw packets no trap got logged. While raw packets and traps from other IP are absolutely fine.

Please look in to the issue and let me know what's going wrong.

Comment: http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmptrap-v3.html TRAP v3 requires very different configuration, so it is not surprising to see wrong messages being dropped.

Comment: Hey  Lex Li, it is not the v3 trap. Let me show the trap that, I captured using tcpdump command "15:44:03.815783 IP 10.128.255.194.45406 > 10.7.254.1.snmptrap:  F= U=MotoNorth E= 0x800x000x000xA10x030x520x540x000x010xE90x0A C=noAuth V2Trap(532)  system.sysUpTime.0=1707047213 E:161.3.10.105.13.0="Event received from an Unknown IPAddress. HpSwitch2610-48, snmpTrapOID = .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.77.0.2, eventDescription.76 : I 02/27/19 10:14:03 ports: port 19 is now off-line"

Comment: Please see the output is in double quotes.

Comment: Well, maybe you don't know how to properly read an SNMP packet. This one is a TRAP v2 PDU sent in an SNMP v3 message body (the first few bytes `02 01 03` is the proof). Therefore, everything listed in the NET-SNMP article applies to you.

Comment: Ohh is it? May, you please give me some reference from that, I can understand that packet format. That definitely helps me a lot.
BTW thank you so much, I was not aware of that, your information is very useful to me, actually, I'm just new in this.

Comment: Hope you are not new to use search engines, as typical keywords can lead you to http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SNMPVersion3SNMPv3MessageFormat.htm Tools like Wireshark can automatically analyze such bytes too.